# Passing data from JavaScript code to the a Razor partial view within ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC based application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, partial-views

Here are some details about our development environment:

-DevExpress 20.1.7 ( we are using DevExtreme )

-Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.4.6)

-ASP.NET Core 3.1.0

I canNot do the following with JavaScript because the document javascript object is undefined inside the following razor code.

> @await Html.PartialAsync("UpldPopupContentTmpltPartial", new
> ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "BookId",
> document.getElementById("HiddenSelectedUploadDataType").Value } });

Could someone please give me a detailed explanation with sample code that will show me how I can pass the document.getElementById("HiddenSelectedUploadDataType").Value to the aforementioned partial view?

@yiyi-you  Thank you for your detailed explanation within your answer.
However, I used the following line of code with @Html.Raw , but even though I'm practical if deadline dates for projects are really close, and I have to get stuff done, I still prefer the proper code implementation practices especially when it makes it easier for code reuse in the future and/or security and/or clarity:

> @await Html.PartialAsync("UpldPopupContentTmpltPartial", new
> ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "BookId",
> @Html.Raw("document.getElementById('HiddenSelectedUploadDataType').Value")}
> });

Is the aforementioned code adhere to proper implementation practices?  If yes or no then please do explain.  Appreciate feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: To give you **a detailed explanation**, we need to see your code, what you have attempted to do so far ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1.pass model data to Partial,here is a demo:

TestPartial.cshtml:

```
@model Model1
    <input asp-for="HiddenSelectedUploadDataType" />
    @await Html.PartialAsync("UpldPopupContentTmpltPartial", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "BookId",Model.HiddenSelectedUploadDataType } })
```

Model1:

```
public class Model1
    {
        public string HiddenSelectedUploadDataType { get; set; }
    }
```

UpldPopupContentTmpltPartial.cshtml:

```
<div>@ViewData["BookId"]</div>
```

result：
[image]

2.You can use ajax to pass `document.getElementById("HiddenSelectedUploadDataType").Value`  to action,and action return partial view to view,here is a demo:

TestPartial.cshtml:

```
    @model Model1
    <input asp-for="HiddenSelectedUploadDataType" />
    <div id="partial"></div>
    @section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TestSlick/GetPartial',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    BookId: $("#HiddenSelectedUploadDataType").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#partial').html(data);
                }
            });  
        })
    </script>
    }
TestSlickController：
     

    public IActionResult TestPartial() {
            Model1 m = new Model1 {  HiddenSelectedUploadDataType="sdsss"};
            return View(m);
        }
        public IActionResult GetPartial(string BookId) {
            ViewData["BookId"] = BookId;
            return PartialView("UpldPopupContentTmpltPartial");
        }
```

result：
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation within your answer. However, could you please look at my updated post?  I used Html.Raw but I'm Not sure if it's a good or bad implementation coding practice.